# wordpress theme from scratch: missing display page

Tags: wordpress-theming

So, i'm creating a wordpress theme from scratch. I have everything done, except for the page where the content should be posted. It is missing. what should i do?

These are the only files i have

front-page.php

index.php

Answer (score 1):

A wordpress theme contains normally more than just a index.php file and a page template.

If you have stuffed everything in the index.php file, then have you need to have a look how the Wordpress loop works:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

I would also have a look at one of the 1000s of Wordpress theme development tutorials that are floating around on the net. Here you will find many ways how to structure you theme.